# @CollectionTable does not connect

Tags: spring, jpa

i have the two tables

**Users Table**

```
create table users (
    usernumber int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    username varchar(32) not null,
    password varchar(72) not null,
    displayname varchar(32) not null,
    birthday datetime not null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    firstname varchar(32) not null,
    lastname varchar(32) not null
);
```

**Users Locked Table**

```
create table users_locked (
    idx int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
    usernumber int unsigned not null,
    start_date datetime not null,
    end_date datetime not null,
    memo varchar(32) default '' not null,
    foreign key (usernumber) references users(usernumber) on delete cascade
);
```

and i used @CollectionTable to create the entity associated with the two table

following...

**Users.java**

```
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Users {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UsersID usernumber;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "displayname")
    private String displayname;

    @Embedded
    private PersonalInformation personal;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "users_locked", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "usernumber"))
    private List<LockPeriod> locked;
    // ....
}
```

**LockPeriod.java**

```
@Getter
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Embeddable
public class LockPeriod {

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date start;

    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date end;

    @Column(name = "memo")
    private String memo;
    //....
}
```

but the following error occurs and can not be mapped :

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
```

did I do something wrong?
I am sorry for the lack of English.

Comment: what is "UsersId"? If you simply have an "unsigned int" as id of the `Users` class then why use `@EmbeddedId`?!!

Comment: To stress through the type. there is no other reason.

Comment: so try it without such baggage (i.e just a long/int); the message that your chosen JPA provider gives is utter gibberish (which should be reported to them, to fix the message and give the real reason)